# Cant submit html form after use js script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this html site

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/index.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Scripts/fancyBox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/prototype.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/scriptaculous.js?load=effects"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/Scale.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/fancyBox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
    <title>Countries</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @foreach (var country in Model)
        {
            <a class="fancybox">
                <div class="tooltip">
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("ChangeCulture", "Home", new { lang = country.Culture }))
                    {
                        <!-- onclick="zoomIn('@country.Culture')"-->
                        <input id="@country.Culture" class="@country.Sprite" type="image" name="submit" src="//" />
                        <span class="tooltiptext">@country.Country</span>
                    }
                </div>
            </a>
        }
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox({
            afterShow : function() {
                this.find("form").submit();
            }
        });
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The bottom line is that the flags of countries with tooltips are displayed on the screen and by pressing it is necessary to change the language of the tooltips to the language used in the country. I did this, and now I need to increase the whole screen after receiving the picture with the flag, and then the language would change. I found the fancybox scripts, but after it is inserted, the form is not sent, the selected flag appears in the center, but nothing happens after that, what could be the problem? I have not written to asp and js before

After click on the image I got an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.find is not a function
    at Object.afterShow (Index:119)
    at Function.trigger (jquery.fancybox.pack.js:17)
    at HTMLDivElement._afterZoomIn (jquery.fancybox.pack.js:33)
    at HTMLDivElement.d.complete (jquery-latest.min.js:4)
    at j (jquery-latest.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-latest.min.js:2)
    at i (jquery-latest.min.js:4)
    at m.fx.tick (jquery-latest.min.js:4)
```

My method

```
public ActionResult ChangeCulture(string lang)
        {
            var returnUrl = this.Request.UrlReferrer?.AbsolutePath;
            var cookie = this.Request.Cookies["lang"];
            if (cookie != null)
            {
                cookie.Value = lang;
            }
            else
            {
                cookie = new HttpCookie("lang")
                {
                    HttpOnly = false,
                    Value = lang,
                    Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1)
                };
            }
            this.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
            return this.Redirect(returnUrl ?? "Index");
        }
```

Comment: Have you found JS errors in browser's console? `$(this).closest("form").submit()` usually work.

Comment: Yes, I got an error and have been placed it to question

Comment: Try `console.log(this)` in `$(".fancybox").fancybox`. What you've get? I think you should use `$(this).find("form").submit();` instead.

Comment: If I use `$(this).find("form").submit();` I havent any errors but form doesnt submit

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto, Its in a loop - thats invalid html because of the duplicate `id` attributes

Comment: @SmiLe, What make you think it does not submit? And what is the signature of your `ChangeCulture()` method?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I placed brealpoint in method and that method change coockie with another language and redirect to page

Comment: @StephenMuecke Oh I see that duplicated ones. So I think using single form & putting foreach loop inside the form might working though? Also OP doesn't show action method contents.

Comment: Added method in question

Comment: `this.Redirect(returnUrl ?? "Index")` looks weird, `Redirect` itself requires full path or URL to redirect. Why not trying `RedirectToAction` when `returnUrl` is null or empty?

Answer (score 1):

You should user jquery selector

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox({
            afterShow : function() {
                $(".fancybox").submit();
            }
        });
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is located in this statement:

```
this.find("form").submit();
```

You're trying to call `find()` method on plain JS object inside `this` wrapper, where the function belongs to a jQuery object. The correct way is using jQuery object like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox({
            afterShow : function() {
                // alternative: use $(this).closest("form").submit();
                $(this).find("form").submit();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Additionally your redirection method in controller action should be like below, since `Controller.Redirect` requires full path or URL for redirect to another page:

```
public ActionResult ChangeCulture(string lang)
{
    var returnUrl = this.Request.UrlReferrer?.AbsolutePath;

    // cookie settings here

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
    {
        return this.RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return this.Redirect(returnUrl);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `this` in `this.find("form")` is not  `$(".fancybox")` here.

Try using `$('.fancybox form')` instead.